# como crear sintaxis de busqueda condicionada en select

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, select

Resulta que quiero hacer una busqueda a travez de ajax donde tengo tres campos uno es idpaciente otro es cedula y el otro es nombre.

Lo que quiero hacer es hacer busqueda primero por idpaciente si no encuentra buscar por cedula y si no encuentra cedula buscar `like ´%$nombre%´` para que lance los resultados mas sercanos de el nombre enviado pero resulta que en mi select solo responde a la ultima condicion de buscar por nombre ya que uso separador or mas abajo le dejo el codigo para que tengan una idea.

```
<?php 
include('../conexion.php');
$idp=$_POST['idp']; #idpaciente
$cd=$_POST['cd'];   #cedula
$n=$_POST['n'];     #nombre
?>
<table class="tblmicentro">
<tr>
<th>idp</th>
<th>Nombre</th>
<th>Apellidos</th>
<th>Nacionalidad</th>
<th>Cedula</th>
<th>acciones</th>
</tr>
<?php 
$n2="0";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM perfil_paciente where (idpaciente='$idp' or cedula='$cd') or nombres like '%$n%'";
$result2=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
while ($m2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
$n2++;
?>
<tr>
<td><span class="numeracion"><?php echo $n2 ?></span></td>
<td><span class="numeracion"><?php echo $m2['idpaciente'] ?></span></td>
<td><?php echo $m2['nombres'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $m2['apellidos'] ?></td>
<td><?php echo $m2['nacionalidad'] ?></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php 
} 
?>
</table>
```

gracias.

Comment: Siu quitas los parentisis en el where que te devuelve??

Comment: no asi lo tenia en un principio y no me devolvio les puse los parentesis a ver si me dividia los or para que busque en orden de colunna

Comment: Probá estructurando la consulta así: "SELECT * FROM perfil_paciente where (idpaciente='".$idp."' or cedula='".$cd."') or nombres like '%".$n."%';". La forma en la que estás usando SQL es correcta.

Comment: me da error en la escritura del codigo!! con esa forma

Comment: si ese codigo es la respuesta ajax no deberia tener algun echo?

Comment: @avvedev el ajax envia ese codigo directo a la pagina dinamica que tengo en otra me rellan la informacion correctamente el problema es al filtrar y el ejemplo del amigo arriba funciona igual como lo tengo

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo así, he comentado el código que he añadido:

```
    <?php 
    include('../conexion.php');
    $idp=$_POST['idp']; #idpaciente
    $cd=$_POST['cd'];   #cedula
    $n=$_POST['n'];     #nombre
    ?>
    <table class="tblmicentro">
    <tr>
    <th>idp</th>
    <th>Nombre</th>
    <th>Apellidos</th>
    <th>Nacionalidad</th>
    <th>Cedula</th>
    <th>acciones</th>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    $n2="0";
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM perfil_paciente where idpaciente='$idp'";
    $result2=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){//si obtenemos datos adelante
while ($m2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $n2++;
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="numeracion"><?php echo $n2 ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="numeracion"><?php echo $m2['idpaciente'] ?></span></td>
    <td><?php echo $m2['nombres'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $m2['apellidos'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $m2['nacionalidad'] ?></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
}else{//sino probamos la segunda opción
$n2="0";
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM perfil_paciente where cedula='$cd'";
    $result2=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
if(mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)){//si obtenemos datos perfecto
while ($m2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $n2++;
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="numeracion"><?php echo $n2 ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="numeracion"><?php echo $m2['idpaciente'] ?></span></td>
    <td><?php echo $m2['nombres'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $m2['apellidos'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $m2['nacionalidad'] ?></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
}else{//si no obtenemos datos, probamos la tercera y ultima opcion
$n2="0";
    $sql2="SELECT * FROM perfil_paciente where nombres like '%$n%'";
    $result2=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql2);
while ($m2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {
    $n2++;
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><span class="numeracion"><?php echo $n2 ?></span></td>
    <td><span class="numeracion"><?php echo $m2['idpaciente'] ?></span></td>
    <td><?php echo $m2['nombres'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $m2['apellidos'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $m2['nacionalidad'] ?></td>
    <td></td>
    </tr>
    <?php 
    } 
}
}

    ?>
    </table>
```